Use keys not defined in KeyboardModifier in PyQt6
I'm trying to use keys that are not defined in the in-built KeyboardModifier defined in PyQt6. I already have functionalities assigned to Ctrl, Shift, Alt.
I'm trying to use the letter keys or number keys (Not the ones defined in KeypadModifier, but the standard number keys). I was wondering if it was possible to create a custom modifier, or another way to check what key is pressed along with a mousePressEvent.
I tried the following code:
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QWidget

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        # Check if the left mouse button is pressed
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            # Check if the key "1" is pressed
            if event.key() == Qt.Key_1:
                print("Left mouse button and number key 1 pressed simultaneously")
                # Handle the event accordingly

        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        # Check if the key pressed is the number key "1"
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_1:
            print("Number key 1 pressed")
            # Handle the event accordingly

        super().keyPressEvent(event)

But I get this error:
AttributeError: 'QMouseEvent' object has no attribute 'key'
So I was wondering if there was another way to achieve this.
Thanks in advance!

The mousePressEvent handler isn't needed. The state of the mouse-buttons can be queried independently via QApplication.mouseButtons() within the keyPressEvent handler.

You can create properties within your class that describe the current states of the LMB and RMB, change them in the mousePressEvent and mouseReleaseEvent, as well as check them in keyPressEvent.
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtGui import QMouseEvent


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.lmb_pressed = False  # is left mouse btn pressed?
        self.rmb_pressed = False  # is right mouse btn pressed?

    def mousePressEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent):
        if event.button() is Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
            self.lmb_pressed = True
        elif event.button() is Qt.MouseButton.RightButton:
            self.rmb_pressed = True
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent) -> None:
        if event.button() is Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
            self.lmb_pressed = False
        elif event.button() is Qt.MouseButton.RightButton:
            self.rmb_pressed = False
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        # Check if LMB pressed
        if self.lmb_pressed:
            if event.key() == Qt.Key_1:
                print("Number key 1 pressed with LMB")

        # Check if the key pressed is the number key "1"
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_1:
            print("Number key 1 pressed")
            # Handle the event accordingly

        super().keyPressEvent(event)

